# Image is not showing in frontend when we call the phtml file in CMS page

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-pages, slider

My requirement is to create a slider without using extension. So I have created a phtml file with the html code and script for slider and called this phtml file in a  cms page. But in the frontend the images are not showing though the script is working.

[image]

Could anyone please help me?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="../image1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image1">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="../image2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Getting the error:

[image]

Comment: Pls share your phtml code to debug

Comment: @aravind, I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your image html with below code.

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image1.jpg') ?>" style="width:100%" alt="image1">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image2.jpg') ?>" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/img_mountains_wide.jpg') ?>" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>
```

Also you have to upload this images files in

> app/design/[Vendor_Theme]/[Theme_Name]/web/images

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I have tried but still not showing the image and I'm getting the error in console which is attached in the question

Comment: Have you added like this <?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/img_mountains_wide.jpg') ?>

Make sure you have added the "images".

And if you magento deploy mode is not set to developer, you have to run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" command

Comment: yes I have added as you said. What should I do now?

Comment: Have you added images in "app/design/[Vendor_Theme]/[Theme_Name]/web/images"

Comment: Yes, I have added the images into the path app/design/vendor/theme/web/images

Comment: If your magento deploy mode is not set to developer, you have to run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" command and clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Your Image Path in Phtml file with Dynamic URL for Images. Put below code into Image Src.

```
 <img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image1.jpg') ?>" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
```

Please Update.